# Layering issues with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a drag and drop question where the user drops an arrow on a specific part of a photo. The photo will have 4 black rectangles on it labeled `A, B, C, D` and the arrows will be `1, 2, 3, 4`. My goal is to layer the rectangle "drop zones" on top of the photo (of a pulley system). Then the arrows will be dropped in the proper drop zone and after each arrow is dropped it will return a string denoting the location of the arrows ie: `2A, 3B, 4C` etc..

*what I have right now the photo is stuck inside of the dropzone rectangle and therefore no arrow can be dropped on top of the photo. I was hoping someone could help. Here is what I have*

```
``$<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>js drag and drop</title>
<style type="text/css">

*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.dragzone
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

.dropzone
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 7%;

}



</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="dragzone">

<img src="orange_T.png" id="dragelement" height="80px"     ondragstart="dragStart (event)">

<img src="red_T.png" id="dragelement" height="80px"    ondragstart="dragStart     (event)">
</div>

<div class="dropzone" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" >

<div class="picture" >
    <img src="C:\Users\Claire Peters\Desktop\Research\pulleys haptic     screenshots\1.1.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:400px;height:400px;">

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

`
and

```
var id;
 function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev)
{
    id=ev.target.id;
     //alert(id);
}

 function drop(ev)
{
    ev.target.append(document.getElementById(id));
    event("dropped!")
}
```